# Not able to enable Diagnostics for web role using powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-web-roles, azure-powershell

Hi I am trying to enable the diagnostics for web role but when ran the script I got the below error
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-dotnet-diagnostics

```
$storage_name = "testdeploy"
$key = "keyvalue"
$config_path="E:\Tempvs\AzureCloudService3\AzureCloudService3\bin\Release\app.publish\Extensions\PaaSDiagnostics.MvcWebRole1.PubConfig.xml"
$service_name="testmyjsdiag"
$storageContext = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storage_name -StorageAccountKey $key
Set-AzureServiceDiagnosticsExtension -StorageContext $storageContext -DiagnosticsConfigurationPath $config_path -ServiceName $service_name -Slot Production -Role MvcWebRole1
```

> Set-AzureServiceDiagnosticsExtension : Cannot bind parameter
>   'StorageContext'. Cannot convert the
>   "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.AzureStorageContext" value of
>   type  "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.AzureStorageContext" to
>   type
>   "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Common.Storage.AzureStorageContext".
>   At E:\TK_Backup\Drive\PowerShell Scripts\Enable Web Role
>   Diagnostics.ps1:6 char:54
>   + ... reServiceDiagnosticsExtension -StorageContext $storageContext -Diagno ...
>   +                                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-AzureServiceDiagnosticsExtension], ParameterBindingException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.ServiceManagement.Extensions.SetAzureServiceDiagnosticsExtensionCommand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems a known issue, all such parameters should have been changed to the common interface type `IStorageContext`, so that they are independent of the storage account version.

As a workaround, we can use `Set-AzureServiceDiagnosticsExtension` cmdlet by using the `-StorageAccountName` and `-StorageAccountKey`, like this:

```
Set-AzureServiceDiagnosticsExtension -StorageAccountName $storage_name -StorageAccountKey $key
```

Also we can use this script to get the context:

```
$StorageAccount= Get-AzureStorageAccount -Name "YouStorageAccount"
$context= $StorageAccount.Context
```

Here a similar case, please refer to [it](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/3979).